# Visual studio keyboard shortcut to go to end of line in Windows

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard

I'm using visual studio community 2017. I want to remap the keyboard shortcut that moves the caret to the end of line (since I'm working on a laptop without the "End" key).

I know how to remap visual studio keys, but I can't find the menu item for it. Do you know what is the menu/action name for it so I can change it?

I can't find the answer on the web though it was asked several times.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The command name is **Edit.LineEnd**. You can assign a new shortcut to it in Visual Studio keyboard options.

Assign the shortcut in the "Text Editor" scope (rather than the default "Global" scope).

When done correctly, it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works great.

Comment: I tried adding the end key, but it requires another button push as well.

Comment: @Demodave If you have an end-key, isn't it already functioning as it should?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Assigned Ctrl+E for this, but it doesn't do anything - just makes the "no shortcut" sound.

Comment: @jameshfisher Have you assigned the shortcut in the Text Editor scope?

Comment: Aha, it works! Thanks! If you don't mind, I'll edit your answer with clarification and a screenshot

Answer (score 5):

Using a circa 2018 macbook pro without explicit labels for home or end, no system or extra configuration is required:

```
Begin of Line: Fn+LeftArrow
End of Line: Fn+RightArrow
Top of Document/Home: Fn+UpArrow
Bottom of Document: Fn+DownArrow
```

This took a little bit of overdue google-research, but a solution or answer lies in this post:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/what-key-on-the-macbook-pro-is-the-end-key-to/2b3517d7-2cf5-4c33-a53e-9d229f6f36f9

While this is specific to MacBooks of a certain era, it may possibly apply more broadly.

Answer (score 5):

This is the way to go:

[image]

Don't forget to change Global to Text Editor.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to do something similar with key mappings in Visual Studio before, and I couldn't find any options. What I ended up using was [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/), and with it you can set up a key bind really quickly. Hope this helps!

Comment: Can't believe Microsoft missed that. It's a real pain when running windows on a Macbook. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

For me, fn + end (the reverse is fn + *home* button) moves the curser to the end of the current line of code, in visual studio.

Note, the fn button has to be enabled. For dell, you press the Esc + the fn button to enable/disable it.